# Magento 2 - Site not loading properly in Developer mode

Tags: magento2, product, static-content, page-layouts, developer-mode

I am working on M2 and I've set M2 developer mode. My site home page works fine but the other pages are not loading. They just show errors and warnings on inner pages.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you have to fix those mentioned errors

Answer (score 1):

Check layout of specific files in your module or theme where this error is showing.

> if you are using linux / ssh ( run this command it would find and list
>   the file where this is added / declared )

```
grep -r -i --include \*.xml '<css' app/design/frontend/
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: This error is showing on product detail page and also other inner pages.

Comment: if you could post screenshot, that would be much better to understand or update it to your question.

Comment: Screenshot is posted already.

Comment: @ShoaibSaleem after using `grep` command

Comment: also check the `error` logs

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an error on the theme **XML** files.

The `<css>` tag must only be located as child of the `<head>` tag.

I would suggest to run `grep` command to locate all the files with the `<css>` tag and look out for the tag's parent if its only under the `<head>`

You may refer to 
`vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/head.xsd`

to check what elements should be under the `<head>` tag